# Can Homebrew be used to install AppleScript bundles?

Tags: applescript, homebrew

Can Homebrew be used to install AppleScript bundles?  If so, what sorts of conventions would the project need to follow?  Would it need to include a make.scpt file compile the `.applescript` files?  I'm assuming that it could reference Github projects.

** edit **

[homebrew-cask](https://github.com/phinze/homebrew-cask) is probably the right tool for this; I submitted an [issue](https://github.com/phinze/homebrew-cask/issues/1049).

Answer (score 1):

This should be possible to call Apple Script like this one for example since it is a command line tool: https://github.com/dronir/SpotifyControl/

After that I don't know if Apple Script are accepted on homebrew maintainer.